# Ejecutar doble click, al dar click en un boton

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, click

Tengo un DatePicker pero este muestra el calendario al darle doble click, coloque un boton para que al darle click al boton este ejecute un doble click en el DatePicker para que muestre el calendario.
No tengo una idea de como hacer asi que agradezco su ayuda.
Realmente no se si se puede hacer eso pero si se puede hacer necesito que me ayuden.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que intentaste o investigaste por favor, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que se abra el DatePicker al hacer un unico click puedes asignarle un evento de raton:

```
DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();
picker.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        picker.show();
    }
});
```

Lo mismo que si quieres establecer el evento en el botón.

```
    Button boton = new Button();
    boton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {
            picker.show();
        }
    });
```